# How to copy SUMIF formula to entire Column without the range changing in Google sheets

Tags: range, sumifs

I am trying to copy and paste the following formula to an entire column without the range changing :

=SUMIF('Incident Log'!$A2:$A, A2, 'Incident Log'!$E2:$E)

when I drag the cursor to paste the formula to the cell underneath it, it pops up:

=SUMIF('Incident Log'!$A3:$A, A3, 'Incident Log'!$E3:$E)

and i need it to be:

=SUMIF('Incident Log'!$A2:$A, A3, 'Incident Log'!$E2:$E)

How can I accomplish this? I thought "$" made my range absolute and that it would keep the range even when pasted the formula to other cells.

Comment: You need to drag and drop the cell, rather than copy/paste it.

Comment: @AJPerez That's what i'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I my formula was:
=SUMIF('Incident Log'!$A2:$A, A2, 'Incident Log'!$E2:$E)

and needed to be
=SUMIF('Incident Log'!$A$2:$A, A2, 'Incident Log'!$E$2:$E)

in order for it to drag copy the formulas the way I wanted it to.